# InDesign: how to automatically cycle through dates using text variables

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I am making a Diary in InDesign with a week to a page set up, I want to create a start date and have the variable text cycle through the rest automatically like page numbers? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text variables don't work that way. InDesign *does* have a way to consecutively number things, however, using a special option for Numbered List in the "Bullets and Numbering" section of Paragraph Styles.

I'm going to assume that you have a text frame for each date in your calendar, and that all you need to update is the number of the day.

- Set up a new paragraph style with the formatting you need for your numbers.
- In the "Bullets and Numbering" section, choose `Numbers` for the `List Type`.
- In the "Numbering Style" section, choose `1, 2, 3, 4` as the Format and remove everything in the `Number` field except `^#`. If you use a particular Character Style for the number, select that in the `Character Style` field.
- Make sure the `Mode` is `Continue from Previous...`.
- Click on the `List:` dropdown (directly below the `List Type:` field, choose `New...` and give it a name. ("List1" is the default, but you might want to name it something more descriptive, like "Date".) Make sure that "Continue Numbers across stories" is checked.

[image]

At this point, all you need is a paragraph in each Story (non-threaded text frame) containing at least a single blank space with that Paragraph Style. You'll override the first one on the page using the regular "Bullets and Numbering" section of the Paragraph panel (not the Paragraph *Style* panel), changing the `Mode` to `Start At` and adding the starting number.

All of them on the page will update based on the number you have assigned to the first one. The numbering will *continue* on subsequent pages, in fact. You just have to insert a "Start At" whenever you need to start a new month.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using Data Merge feature in Indesign. I made a table with dates and days in excel and saved it as a csv file. Then I mapped Textboxes on single Indesign page to the columns in excel(with 365 rows). Got awesome results in one single click on Create Merged Document. I also had motivational quotes in excel that appeared on top of each page of the Diary.

Though it's an old query, but I hope it helps others seeking something similar.

Peace!
Sachin